# Why the numeric wrapper class need to provide static toString() method?

Tags: java, wrapper

I wonder that how it would help us in practice while writing code. In Java numeric wrapper class has overloaded static **toString()** method and return String representation of the parameter.
Is it common approach to use this methods?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's common to *invoke* the existing methods on the wrapper classes or to add static `toString` methods to your own classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You could use it whenever you want the `String` value of a number. Alternatively, you can use [`String.valueOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) note that the Javadoc refers to [`Integer.toString(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) where the second `int` is the radix.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't common. It's simply a convenience method to use instead of having to box the argument into a wrapper object and then call `toString` on it. Since you can't define any more primitives, only objects, overriding the non-static `toString` is the way to go in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful when you need to convert a variable of a primitive type to a String without creating a wrapper object.

Like this:

```
int a = 5;
String str = Integer.toString(a);
```

Comment: Or you can just say `a + ""`

Comment: If you say `a + ""` you'll create two extra variables: one for an empty string, other for `a` converted to a string. And a third will be for result of concatenation. In most cases it doesn't matter, our computers are rather powerful, but I don't think it's beautiful solution.